# WTH (NOLOCK) syntax fo subquery

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, nolock

I am trying to add with (nolock) in a report query that when run locks the full db making imposssible for other users to use the db.

I can't figure out how to use in this case:

```
-- this is just an example:
SELECT FIELDS FROM (SELECT * FROM ATABLE) AS SUB
```

This gives syntax error:

```
SELECT FIELDS FROM (SELECT * FROM ATABLE) WITH (NOLOCK) AS SUB
```

where `WITH (NOLOCK)` shuold be put?

I am not saying this is a solution to all problems, it is just a test i want to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are more tables involved and more than one query invloved and you don't care about dirty reads then set the *Isolation level* of your transaction to `read uncommited` instead of writing `Nolock` everywhere

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
```

Comment: in my context if before the SELECT statement i write this command i obtain the same result- i just made a test . thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would put it here but the thing to note is you are using a view so really it should go on the tables in the view:

```
SELECT FIELDS FROM (SELECT * FROM MYVIEW WITH (NOLOCK)) AS SUB
```

Answer (score 1):

If you care about accuracy you shouldn't put it anywhere on your report. That hint has some very interesting things it does that many people don't fully understand. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

But if you are deadset on continuing, table hints belong next to the table. Of course since this is a view it isn't going to help much.

```
SELECT FIELDS FROM (SELECT * FROM MYVIEW WITH (NOLOCK)) AS SUB
```

Comment: Thanks. I modified the example using ATABLE instead than MYVIEW, now the syntax is fine thanks. I now about the risks of no lock but in my context i know it is an acceptable risk to take because of the context.

Comment: Cool. Sometimes for reports having the results be close is ok.